# Stacked bars in a barchart with individual and overall labels

Tags: plotting

There are a lot of questions here about formatting of barcharts, but I couldn't find one matching mine. I seek to display data in stacked format, labeling each component of the stack and the total for each bar. I can't make it work for the life of me.

As a starting place, consider

```
BarChart[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLabels -> {Range[2004, 2006], None}]
```

I want each component labeled as below --

[image: goal]

My efforts to date result in some pieces appearing but never all, and often in the wrong places.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
BarChart[Labeled[#, Total[#], Above] & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}, 
         ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartLabels -> {Range[2004, 2006], None}, 
         LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 was about to post but you got there while I was still eating my breakfast :)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: LOL, I'm usually last to the party re:plotting/graphics against you and other plot wizards - it just happens I needed this very layout not long ago... thanks for + !